# Accessing facebook information using v3.1 Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, api

Hoping someone can help.

I've been using the facebook graphAPI to try access the reactions that are sent to my live video streams.

The intention is to roll this into a node app but so far I've been experimenting using the Graph API explorer with 0 luck. I'm unable to get any information from the API explorer, or even normal curl commands.

I created my user access token for my app.

From here I'm trying to do basic stuff like my personal information using GET requests but all that is returned is

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 1,
    "error_subcode": 1357045,
    "message": "unknown error (empty response)",
    "type": "http",
    "status": 0
  }
}
```

I have also tried within my browser but which returns slightly more information. I send this command

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/LADbible/posts?access_token={MY_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

and receive back

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 10,
      "fbtrace_id": "E7wq6wibV7N"
   }
}
```

I have been scouring the internet for more information on this, all the information and tutorials for the API pre v2.11 seem to work as it should, but I'm getting no luck at all now.

Would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my own problem. Stupidly I left open an extension that was blocking the call from the Graph Explorer